# How to find the Sum and Average of an Array list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

So far I've only attempted to do the sum of the array and already got stuck.
Honestly I just need to find the sum and average of the array list and print them to html. 
Here's my code:

```
//Global Variables
var values = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140];

for (i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
sum += values[i];
}

document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
```

Comment: average is the sum divided by the number of elements - is that the issue?

Comment: `var sum = values.reduce((a,b) => a+b), avg = sum / values.length;`

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++ ){
    sum += parseInt( elmt[i], 10 ); //don't forget to add the base
}

var avg = sum/elmt.length;

document.write( "The sum of all the elements is: " + sum + " The average is: " + avg );

document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
```